# How to debug with Rubymine, Docker-Compose and multiple debug sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, rubymine, ruby-debug-ide

I am experimenting with Rubymine's "Docker-Compose" integration. I normally do the "usual" debugging, by using the and "BUG"-buttons to start a debug session.

Normally I can start these sessions for the "rails server"- itself and one for debugging within the "rails console"- and the "rspec"-commands simultaneously. That's no problem when working "the old way" and works perfectly.

Old way means: running a

- rails console AND rails server in debug session
- MySQL
- Elasticsearch
- Redis
- ...

on my local machine.

But with the `docker-compose`-configuration I have to do that differently:

I followed that tutorial (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#configure_ruby_docker_integration) to set up a **singular debug session**, but I was not able to find out how to use **more than one debug session** at once. (adding `rails console` in debug session while `rails server`'s debug session is still running). Somehow they are conflicting. It's no problem to start a regular `rails console` in Rubymine while a `rails server`debug session is running

All tutorials and videos I found were only covering the most basic cases, but not mine.

- Is this possible?
- Do I have to change the debug port / open another one for the second session? (I didn't found how to change the Rubymine attached debugger port, it's fixed to "3000:3000"), it is "hardcoded in the appended `docker-compose.override.1234.yml`-file.

My containers are running

Rails Development Server Configuration
[image: Rails Development Server Configuration]

Rails Console Configuration
[image: Rails Console Configuration]

Comment: The easy way is use `docker-compose run` for docker-compose option, to have different running container for each session

Comment: There are 2 related issue on RubyMine's tracker, please take a look:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-25522
and
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20874

Comment: @Olivia thank you, I'll watch this and will post the solution when it's get solved